# Not able to access svg files when application is deployed on Weblogic server

Tags: svg, web, web-applications, weblogic, mime-types

svg images are working fine when the application is running on tomcat server.
But when I deploy the application on weblogic server , svg images are not displayed.

Can anyone let me know what could be the problem? Do I need to configure mime-type for svg inside Weblogic ?

Comment: First, check your weblogic access logs to see if svg files are sent by weblogic with a http code 200

Answer (score 7):

You have to provide mimetype mapping in web.xml to make it work. See the example below.

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

put that inside your web.xml under web-app tag.

Answer (score 0):

The below link might give you some ideas:

http://www.techpaste.com/2014/06/steps-configure-mime-types-weblogic-11g/

You can try configuring mime type as explained in the link above.